# How to display rows in mysql table based on varying external values

Tags: php, mysql

I hope someone can help with the following... I have multiple product names in a MYSQL database table on one hand and on the other hand I am getting some info such as pricing (excluding product name and some other static info) from xml feeds. The xml feed gives a product code, with which I can match the rows I need in the database because the database includes name of the product but also product code whilst xml doesn't include name of the product.

What I want to do is to fetch the name of the product and some other values from the database and link them with the other info from the xml, so that the end result is that I display the name of the products and the other info on the front-end. There are multiple products from multiple xml's...

If this was single product with a single code, I know I can use the SELECT statement with a where clause, wherein the WHERE clause is the product ID, but because I have multiple products with multiple ID's and I don't need to fetch everything from the database (but only those products displayed/searched for on the front-end), I am a bit stuck and don't know how to do this.

I hope this makes sense. If not, please do let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include your code.

Comment: what code exactly? You want to see an xml response for example? The mysql query code is not written yet because don't know what query to use.

Comment: Oh. Do you have a sample of your desired result?

Comment: If you have multiple product IDs coming from the XML, you can do `WHERE product_id IN (id1, id2, id3, ...)`

Comment: You can use PHP's `implode` function to construct the list of IDs that you put into the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Barmar, thanks for your reply. Problem is, it's difficult to predict/know which codes will come back. They come back dynamically based on search of customer for product... There are over 100,000 products.

Comment: You just extract them all from the XML feed, put them into an array, and call `implode`.

Comment: @mush When you want to send a comment to someone, put @ before their name.

Comment: sorry about that @Barmar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're processing the XML feed, put all the product codes into an array. Then you can construct the SQL query dynamically from this:

```
$codes_string = implode(', ', $product_codes);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM product_table WHERE product_id IN ($codes_string)";
```

I'm assuming product IDs are numeric IDs. If they're strings you'll need to put quotes around each of them:

```
$codes_string = implode("', '", $product_codes);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM product_table WHERE product_id IN ('$codes_string')";
```

Comment: interesting... That leads to another question. How do you get only the product codes in the $product_codes variable. At moment, I am looping through the xml and echoing individual node values. I am creating objects from the response, but can create an array. But how then do I capture only the product ID values in the variable? Thanks.

Comment: I assume the product codes are in specific XML nodes, like `<product_code>1234</product_code>`. So when you're looping through the XML, you get it from those nodes.

Comment: yes, echoing those node values is not a  problem. But how do I capture them into a single variable, such as $product_codes so I can use that variable in the query? Thanks.

Comment: In your loop, you do `$product_codes[] = $this_node_contents;` to add the contents to the array.

Comment: Okay, so am I understanding it right that it's pretty much like creating the loop startpoint  itself? At the moment, I have 
foreach($output->availableProducts as $availableProducts)
so I just turn this into
$output->availableProducts->ProductCode[ ] = $productcodearray;
Am I understanding it correctly? Thanks.

Comment: Inside that `foreach` loop, you want `$product_codes[] = $availableProducts->product_code;`

Comment: Clear. Thanks a lot. Both your and Lawrence answers where very helpful and if I could accept both I would. I feel that Barmar's answer is a bit simpler for the beginner I am and easiest to implement in my existing code, so I am going ahead and accepting that answer. Thanks both

Answer (score 2):

You could likely use an IN query to get the products from the table. Then you'd have to merge them into an object or array of the rows you got via XML.

```
select * from `mydb`.`myproducts` where product_id in ('key1', 'key2', 'key3');
```

By your comments across the different answers, if you are looking to build your array of product codes, here's the most viable approach:

```
$productIds = array();
foreach ($myXmlRecords as $xmlProduct) {
    array_push($productIds, $xmlProduct->product_id);
}

$query = 'select * from `mydb`.`myproducts` where product_id in (\'' . implode("', '", $productIds) . '\')';
```

Taking it a step farther, if you wanted to join the data of the two instead then I'd do the following:

```
$products = array();
$productIds = array();
foreach ($myXmlRecords as $xmlProduct) {
    $p = new stdClass();
    $p->product_id = $xmlProduct->product_id;
    $p->xmlProp1 = $xmlProduct->prop1;
    $p->xmlProp2 = $xmlProduct->prop2; // basically transfer any Xml properties you want to retain to the new $p object
    array_push($products, $p);
    array_push($productIds, $xmlProduct->product_id);
}
// Now build your query that will grab all matching products you got from Xml
$query = 'select * from `mydb`.`myproducts` where product_id in (\'' . implode("', '", $productIds) . '\')';
// Now match up the results
$results = mysql_query($query);
foreach ($results as $prodRow) {
    foreach ($products as $p) {
        if ($p->product_id == $prodRow->product_id) {
            // These match, now add your db properties to the product
            $p->dbProp1 = $prodRow->prop1;
            $p->dbProp2 = $prodRow->prop2; // and so on
        }
    }
}
```

The end result is an array of products that have the Xml and Db info you want to combine. Before someone corrects me, there is probably a more efficient way than nested foreach statements such as updating the mysql query to use a join against the Xml data and then selecting from both that and your DB. But this is a fast approach that should get you where you need to.

Hope that helps!

Comment: MySQL doesn't use square brackets, that's SQL-Server syntax.

Comment: @LawrenceJohnson doesn't this require me to know what product codes i need to fetch so I can enter the key1, key2 and key3 values for example?

Comment: Yes, my suggestion is assuming you have the product info from the Xml first and then you are querying the database to get the additional product info that you can add to it.

Comment: @LawrenceJohnson problem is that the customer on front-end is searching and he can get a lot of different product ID's depending on the search he performs, is there any other way I can get the name of these product ID's from database and then echo them along with the rest of the xml output... ?

Comment: Oh, so basically: 1) User inputs search, 2) Search queries database, 3) Result queries Xml? My question then would be, do you have a single Xml that returns all products or are you querying an API that will return specific products by matching IDs you got from the database?

Comment: @LawrenceJohnson, 

1. Customer searches by city 
2. Query API that returns XMl/json response to return available products and pricing info for that city.
3. XML/JSON response only includes pricing data and product codes and some other info but not names for example
4. Now, want to pull that static info (such as product name) from database. Database has product name and also a column with product ID. 

Hope this makes sense. Please let me know if it doesn't and thanks for the help.

Comment: If that's the case, the solution above (and Barmar's) will do the trick. That XML you get back from step 2 should be used to create your MySQL query in the answer. Do you need help with that piece as well?

Comment: @LawrenceJohnson, yes please, just because I am not getting how I can capture all those product codes into a variable for example. Little bit of direction would be great. Thanks.

Comment: OK, I revised with some new options for you to consider.